# Input mask with only past dates validation

Tags: validation, jquery-inputmask

I am using Input mask from this [link](http://digitalbush.com/projects/masked-input-plugin/). My input mask working correctly. But i want validation for past dates only from current date. But i don't get any condition for this.

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 1):

You can use below yearrange hash for setting up the past date validation.

```
$("#date_of_birth").inputmask("mm/dd/yyyy", { yearrange: { minyear: 1900, maxyear: 2015, }});
```